# What is wrong with this javascript code

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I have tried to display alert when the user clicks on the document.As I have done doAlert() with parenthesis, the code runs when the document load and alerts without any events occur but if I do simply

> doAlert

It seems to respond when I click the document. So, is it must that I should call function in javascript without the parenthesis or what is the idea for doing this. What if I were to pass parameter to a function.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function doAlert(){
        alert("Hello");
    }
    function init(){
        document.onclick = doAlert();
    }
    window.onload = init();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a function, you get its return value.

```
window.onload = init();
```

This runs `init()` and sets `window.onload` to its return value, `undefined`.

You need to set it like this:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Now `window.onload` is set to the function `init`, it won't run until it needs to.

If you want to pass parameters, like in your `onClick`, you can do it like this:

```
document.onclick = function(){
    doAlert('Clicked');
};
```

This sets `onClick` to an anonymous function, that calls the functions you want.  Or, you can use a closure:

```
function doAlert(param){
  return function(){
    alert(param);
  };
};

document.onClick = doAlert('Hello World');
```

`doAlert` is called, `onClick` is set to its return value, which is a function (in this case one that alerts `'Hello World'`).

Comment: Good explanation ... Much clear now. I was infact calling the function  while I was setting function to event. Very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @insane-36: No problem.  Functions in JavaScript can be treated as variables, it's weird.  It's because `function a(){}` is the same as doing `var a = function(){}`.

Answer (score 8):

If `foo` is a function, then `bar = foo` will assign that function to the variable `bar`, but `bar = foo()` will *immediately* call the function and assign its *return value* to `bar` instead.

Event handlers work by being given a function that will be called when the event happens. If you run the function immediately then its return value needs to be a function that you want to run when the event happens (in this case the return value of both `doAlert` and `init` is `undefined`).

Comment: Quentin has it right, your code is executing the call the function, not assigning it as the handler.

Comment: Easier to understand, but tangled me ... Thank you

Answer (score 6):

document.onclick is being set to the *return* of doAlert and not the doAlert function itself.

Your code should look like:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function doAlert(){
        alert("Hello");
    }
    function init(){
        document.onclick = doAlert;
    }
    window.onload = init;
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Functions in Javascript are objects and can be passed along like any other variable. In your case, `doAlert` is just a reference to a function. In order to call the function pointed by this reference, you need to use parenthesis : `doAlert()`.

The `document.onclick` method is supposed to be a function reference, so you assign it a function reference like this : `document.onclick = doAlert`. With your syntax, you assign the result of a call to `doAlert()` to `document.onclick`, which is incorrect.

Got it ? :)